# How to change NGINX server name

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, mod-rewrite

In the Apache web server we can change the server signature (Apache Name) using mod_rewrite.

For example - http://www.howtoforge.com/changing-apache-server-name-to-whatever-you-want-with-mod_security-on-debian-6

How would I do the same with Nginx? I am new to Nginx and want to replace the Nginx name with my own signature.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 Server Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For nginx, you will need to compile in the [headers more module](http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule) (it is not included with nginx by default). This will allow you to override the `Server:` header.

After that, you can simply do:

```
more_set_headers "Server: my_phone/1.0"
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. which file i've to edit? can you put here commands? I'm totally Newbie for NGINX :(

Answer (score 0):

A. http://wiki.nginx.org/NginxHttpHeadersMoreModule#more_set_headers

B. Edit source code and replace `ngx_http_server_string` value

C. [Beta] Use modsecurity

D. [not recommended] Use reverse-proxy like Varnish or Squid to hide header (headers will be resolvable when accessing localhost)

Comment: thanks for the reply. which file I've to edit?

Comment: http://hg.nginx.org/nginx/file/b95e70ae6bcd/src/http/ngx_http_header_filter_module.c
 line 49

Comment: note, it's still possible to recognize, that it's not IIS

Comment: thanks for the help. so what is best way to hide/change Server name? except Cloudflare.

Comment: depends on what do you use for dynamic pages. hard to tell.